# Creating SQL table with column name "Return"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to create the following SQL table, using the query:

```
 create table Return_indiv (Date datetime, issueid varchar(255), Return varchar(255))
```

As you see, one of the columns names is "Return". However, SQL believes it is the function `return`, and gives the following error:

```
 Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Return'.
 Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
 'varchar' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Any way I could overcome this error? Thanks!

Comment: Quote the column name. Or but in brackets.

Comment: Better yet, don't use reserved keywords when naming your objects.

Comment: Please dude.  Don't use a reserved word.  Whoever inherits your code will thank you a thousand times over.  "ReturnValue" ?  Please, I'm begging you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Side note: I am not a dude!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add brackets around the column name since it's a keyword:

```
create table Return_indiv 
(
    Date datetime, 
    issueid varchar(255), 
    [Return] varchar(255)
)
```

Note that you'l also have to use brackets every time you *query* that column in the table (or update, etc.)  With that in mind you need to decide if it's worth it to have a column with the same name as a reserved word.

Also note that `Date` is a keyword in SQL 2008 and above - so if you plan on upgrading it will be necessary to escape that column name as well.

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify a bit, Return is a reserved word in your database (probably a function or something).  So you can't just use it as a table name, column name, etc.  You can get around this by surrounding it with [].  But a much better idea is to not use reserved words in any of your object names.   I can't really tell what will be in that column, but maybe you can name it RETURN_VALUE, RETURN_ITEM, whatever.  Just avoid reserved words, it makes life easier for just about everyone.

Answer (score 4):

put [] around the return keyword

```
create table Return_indiv (Date datetime, issueid varchar(255), [Return] varchar(255))
```

Answer (score 3):

Put in in brackets:

```
create table #temp ([return] varchar(100))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo should use brackets `[]` to avoid the parser understanding your column name as a keyword.

Nevertheless I would advice against using a keyword to name a column or table. It makes difficult for others after you too understand the code. If other developer doesn't know ot is a keyword, can be difficult to understand what is failing on the query, in case there was an error.

Try this

```
USE tempdb
GO

CREATE TABLE Return_indiv
(
    [Date]   DATETIME,
    issueid  VARCHAR(255),
    [RETURN] VARCHAR(255)
)
```